# NOR-conjunction within OR-conjunctions

Tags: logic, boolean-expression

Let's save I have the logical expression

**a OR b NOR c OR d**

Is this interpreted as **(a OR b) NOR (c OR d)** or as **a OR (b NOR c) OR d** ?

It is a specific programming problem I face, thus the question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical operators priority with NAND, NOR, XNOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167779/logical-operators-priority-with-nand-nor-xnor)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it would be interpreted as:

A or b or (Not c) or d