# what is the operator precedence in Boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, digital-logic

As a XOR b NOR c is not equal to a NOR b XOR c,there must be some precedence rule for all operators in Boolean algebra.So what is the precedence rule for XOR,NAND,XNOR,NOR ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical operators priority with NAND, NOR, XNOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167779/logical-operators-priority-with-nand-nor-xnor)

Answer (score 4):

The precedence is NOT > XOR > AND > OR, some of the gates you mention are a combination of two operators in reality. For instance A **NAND** B can be thought  of as **NOT**(A **AND** B).